# Duplicating a google spreadsheet without google drive access via API

Tags: google-sheets-api

I want to duplicate spreadsheets, basically copy of templates to new spreadsheets via google Sheets APIs. There is a [copyTo](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.sheets/copyTo) function that can copy only a specific sheet from a spreadsheet.  But there seems to be no option to copy the whole spreadsheet.  I don't want to access customer google drive for this duplicate need.  Is there any other option to make a copy of the whole google spreadsheet to a new spreadsheet without the need of accessing google drive (or Drive API)?

Answer (score 1):

### You use the method [copy(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#copyname) for spreadsheets

Sample:

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
ss.copy("Copy of " + ss.getName());
```

Comment: Look possible in App script, but I couldn't figure out how to do it in python API.  Any idea how to do it?  I see Python API has '''spreadsheets.get(spreadsheet_id)'''

Comment: This is more complicated. You need 3 steps: 1. [Create a  newspreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create).  2. [Get the content of the template](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get). 3. [Update the content of the new spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate).

Comment: Yeah, it's quite complicated.  to make it a little simpler, I am not trying to 1. create a new spreadsheet, 2. CopyTo sheets from source to new spreadsheet, 3. Renaming the sheets (removing Copy Of string.